# Universe inconsistency (because of strict positivity restriction?)

Tags: coq

I have the following code snippet.

```
Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive Simple (A: Type) := simple : Simple A.
Inductive Wrap (A: Type) :=
| wrap : A -> Wrap A
| funWrap : forall X, Simple X -> (X -> Wrap A) -> Wrap A.

Definition anotherWrap A : Wrap A :=
  funWrap (simple A) (fun x => wrap x).

Fail Definition specialWrap1 A : Wrap (Wrap A) :=
  funWrap (simple (Wrap A)) (fun x => wrap x).

Fail Definition specialWrap A : Wrap A :=
  funWrap (simple (Wrap A)) (fun x => x).
```

My first thought was that the `X` in `funWrap` cannot be instantiated with `Wrap A`, because of the strict positivity restriction for inductive types. Is this the case or is there another reason for the inconsistency (and maybe a different approach to define the function `specialWrap`)?

Edit: The explanation for the second definition is given in a comment of the selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first definition is the lack of universe polymorphism, I think. If you enable `Set Universe Polymorphism.` it will go through.

This is because regular inductive definition are "universe monomorphic" so in this case you get a universe problem due to the shared universe level.

Comment: I wanted to add that I figured out why the second definition does not work (even with your universe polymorphism extension). As mentioned in a [recent paper by Timany and Jacobs](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/513812/2/CIT.pdf) the polymorphic universes extension of Coq does not (yet) support cumulativity for inductive types. My definition above resembles their example of small ensembles.